# "IS NULL" in Zend_Db_Table select not working

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, null, zend-db-table

I'm trying to do a join on 2 tables in Zend, using the DbTable / model / mapper structure.
If, in my mapper, I do this:

```
$select = $this->getDbTable()->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->join('images', 'images.oldFilename =
                                               availablePictures.filename')
               ->where('images.ref IS NOT NULL');
$resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll( $select );
```

it works like a charm, but if I try the same thing with IS NULL instead of NOT NULL, I get nothing where I should get a result set of several rows, just like when I try it directly in MySQL with

```
SELECT *
FROM (
`availablePictures` AS a
LEFT JOIN `images` AS i ON a.filename = i.oldFilename
)
WHERE i.`ref` IS NULL
```

I get the impression Zend doesn't like my IS NULL or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried Zend_Debug::dump($select->__toString());exit; to see the sql it generates? If you copy paste that sql-statement into mysql, do you get the correct results then? If not, what's different from the manually typed version?

Comment: Thank you Machine! Doing so I discovered that Zend was creating an inner join instead of the left join I needed. So, by using ->joinLeft() my issue was solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution was to be found in Machine's comment on my original post.
Doing what he suggested I noticed that Zend created an inner join as I was using the wrong select method, so:

```
$select = $this->getDbTable()->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->joinLeft('images', 'images.oldFilename =
                                               availablePictures.filename')
               ->where('images.ref IS NOT NULL');
$resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll( $select );
```

is how it should be.

Comment: @Karim, I can't! Not for 2 days. Stackoverflow only allows accepting your own answer after 2 days. :)

Answer (score 2):

My thinking is it has to do with the way MySql decides what is NULL and what isn't. Is it possible that the results you are expecting have a default assignment of the empty string `''` or `0` in the `images.ref` column? MySql does *not* treat those as NULLs. Have a look here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: Hey Karim,
thanks for the input, but it is NULL in that column, not '' nor 0, I checked and just double checked. Currently tracing Machine's comment, he is onto something.