# is not null condition in zend framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new to zf and I've started working with zf2, I don't find much documentation for the syntax and all. My issue is how to write `is not null` condition in zf2 syntax.

```
$select->where->notEqualTo('pe_name', '');
```

I've written for `not equal to`, now I need for `is not null`. I don't know how to write this in this syntax. Can anyone who is familiar with this help me.

Comment: You could directly specify `->where('something IS NOT NULL')`. Also have a look [here](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Db.Sql.Where.html#isNotNull).

Comment: possible duplicate of ["IS NULL" in Zend\_Db\_Table select not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417739/is-null-in-zend-db-table-select-not-working)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

got it..!!

```
$select->where->isNotNull('pe_name');
```

and

```
$select->where('pe_name IS NOT NULL');
```

also works.